# Python script is not executing

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def message(to,message=''):
    """this a simple function to send a whatsapp message to your friends
    and group using python and selenium an automated tool to parse the HTML 
    content and to change the properties. 
    
    paramters:
    to - enter a name from your contacts it can be friend's name or a group's title.
    message - message to be deliever"""

    d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/Miguelangel/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
    d.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')                  # URL to open whatsapp web
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver = d, timeout = 900)         # inscrease or decrease the timeout according to your net connection

    message += '\nthis is a system generated message'
    # additional text to with your message to identify that it is send via software
  
    name_argument = f'//span[contains(@title,\'{to}\')]'        # HTML parse code to identify your reciever
    title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,name_argument)))
    title.click()                           # to open the receiver messages page in the browser

    # many a times class name or other HTML properties changes so keep a track of current class name for input box by using inspect elements
    input_path = '//div[@class="pluggable-input-body copyable-text selectable-text"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
    box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,input_path)))

    box.send_keys(message + Keys.ENTER)
```

I execute from my windows console terminal. But it do nothing, no errors. See the following image:

[image]

Comment: That's your whole script? You're never calling `message()`. You have to call your code in order for it to run. If what you shared is not a [mre] then please make one.

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes, thats all my code.

Comment: Your code is executing but as @RandomDavis points out you never call your function you only defined it.

Comment: Your code imports modules from a library and defines a function. There is no code to actively do anything, like e. g. a function call.

Comment: @Mike087 So, why do you expect `message()` to run on its own? Do you understand how functions and function calls work?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new in python. How i call that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this code basically run just remove

```
def message(to,message=''):
```

and make this code flat.
When the basic things will work and code become more complex you will have to split it into functions.
Also `message` should be defined a bit different.
Instead

```py
message += '\nthis is a system generated message'
```

use

```py
message = '\nthis is a system generated message'
```

Also take care about the `to` parameter.
Define it locally.

Comment: `to` and `message` also have to be declared

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @RandomDavis you are right about the `message`, while `to` is never used here.

Comment: @Mike087 Also update the `message` definition as I mentioned in updated version!

Comment: @Prophet yeah it is: `name_argument = f'//span[contains(@title,\'{to}\')]'`

Comment: Ah, OK. You are right...

Comment: Ok. I called the function in the same file at the end with `message(to, message)`. Is Ok doing it that way?

Comment: In case you are doing this with correct indentation - yes.

Comment: @Prophet Yes, I'm using the same indentation as the line `def message(to,message=''):`. Is working now. From what I see, indentation is important in python, unlike the other languajes.

Comment: Sure, it's one of the most basic differences between Python and several other languages (at least those that I know and use) and it often causes problems for the beginners :)